# when hovering on iframe, how do I trigger a class on element outside of iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iframe, hover

I have this page with an iframe. I want to trigger a hover class on an element outside of the iframe. It's not a parent wrapper, it's just a totally different div in the DOM outside of the iframe.

The html:

```
  <body>

    <div class="a6-expander-wrapper"></div>
    <div class="some-other-div"></div>
    <iframe title="My-Iframe" src="//example.com"></iframe>

  </body>
```

The CSS:

```
.a6-expander-wrapper-hover {
    opacity: 1 !important;
}

.a6-expander-wrapper {
      height: 44px;
    width: 44px;
   background-color:red;
   opacity: 0;
}
```

The jquery I'm currently using:

```
var $iframe = $('iframe[title="My-Iframe"]').contents(); 
var hoverItem = $('.a6-expander-wrapper');

$iframe.find('*').mouseover(function () {
    hoverItem.addClass('a6-expander-wrapper-hover');
}).mouseout(function () {
    hoverItem.removeClass('a6-expander-wrapper-hover');
});
```

Here's a plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/2WONkAijTzF2BBsh3p9H?p=preview

None of this is working as you can tell from the plnkr. I'm not sure what to do. Let me know how you'd solve this.

Comment: if the iframe on your server or it's an external page you cannot control?

Comment: Technically it's an iframe of a site on my network (subdomain). I did change the $iframe to iframe but no luck

Comment: `var $iframe` should be `var iframe`… that is one reason… :)  A javascript variable name can only begin with a letter or an underscore

Comment: fixed this but no love.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be what you need. No need to target the iFrame contents then select everything inside. You can just put the mouseover on the iFrame itself.

```
$(function () {
    var iframe = $('iframe[title="My-Iframe"]'); 
    var hoverItem = $('.a6-expander-wrapper');
    $(iframe).mouseover(function () {
        hoverItem.addClass('a6-expander-wrapper-hover');
    }).mouseout(function () {
      hoverItem.removeClass('a6-expander-wrapper-hover');
    });
});
```

Working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/pJdtn9fX8HT9KWSvrOcW?p=preview

Comment: Accepting this one since you included a plnkr. It's always a bit handier. My only issue is that it works in my plnkr example but not in my real environment. I'm not sure why. Still trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly you want to run some code when a user hovers over the iframe.

To do this you can use the following code(After adding it into your code of course):

```
  $('iframe[title="My-Iframe"]').mouseover(function(){
    hoverItem.addClass('a6-expander-wrapper-hover');
  }).mouseout(function(){
    hoverItem.removeClass('a6-expander-wrapper-hover');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

If it does not violate the [Same-origin_policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) the solution is:

```js
$(function () {
  var iframe = $('iframe[title="My-Iframe"]');
  var hoverItem = $('.a6-expander-wrapper');

  iframe.hover(function () {
    hoverItem.addClass('a6-expander-wrapper-hover');
  }, function () {
    hoverItem.removeClass('a6-expander-wrapper-hover');
  });
});
```

```css
.a6-expander-wrapper-hover {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}

.a6-expander-wrapper {
  height: 44px;
  width: 44px;
  background-color:red;
  opacity: 0;
}

iframe {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>


<div class="a6-expander-wrapper"></div>
<div class="some-other-div"></div>
<iframe title="My-Iframe" src="xx.html"></iframe>
```

Comment: can you please give me a suggestion if we have different origin and want to achieve this solution?